# LDAP ModifyAttributes by email

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to modify the attributes on an existing record in LDAP. It seems like the only way tI can get the record is by using a lookup with:

```
ctx.modifyAttributes(CN=Joe blue,cn=user,DC=foo,DC=com" , mods);
```

But I need to get it by email (or login for that matter). I have tried several variations but get a naming exception, for example:

```
ctx.modifyAttributes(&(objectClass=user)(mail=jblow*)),cn=user,DC=foo,DC=com)
```

javax.naming.InvalidNameException: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=jblow*)),cn=user,DC=foo,DC=com: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001BA, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
 '(&(objectClass=user)(mail=jblow*)),cn=user,DC=foo, DC=COM,

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide a search filter for a Modify operation.  You need to provide a full DN as your first example shows.

Therefore, you would first have to do the search for (mail=jblow*) in the base DN of cn=user,dc=foo,dc=com to find the full DN of the object of interest.

Then you can do your Modify, based on the full DN.

Comment: Thx Geoff, that makes total sense now that you point it out. LDAP sure is a different beast!

Answer (score 1):

As geoffc said, you would need to pass the "distinguishedName" to the modifyAttributes function, along with the mods.

You can create a separate function that queries LDAP, based on your search constraints (mail=jblow*), and return the "distinguishedName" String.  Then just pass the function to ctx.modifyAttributes().

```
String dn = distinguishedNameQuery();
ctx.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
```